# Black Screen When Run app on Android

Tags: qt, qt-necessitas

I'm using necessitas 4.1

When the application is running on the emulator or tablet Black screen appears and the program automatically closes.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: See http://sourceforge.net/p/necessitas/tickets/22/, maybe it's related.